# Memory Error in numpy.save() in list of lists but not list of dicts

Tags: python, json, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am creating a dataset, it would ideally be comprised in a list with different lists (matrix).
The final size of the dataset should be `(n_data, 10, 20, 3)`, being n_data the amount of data available.

I receive a list which contains n_data elements, being each one a dict. A test example, instead of `(10,20,3)`, I will use `(3,2,2)`

```
    [{
       '1': '[[1,2], [3,4]]',
       '2': '[[5,6], [7,8]]',
       '3': '[[9,1], [2,3]]'
    },
# there are more elements in the list, n_data amount
]
```

So everything is a string. I can do `json.loads()` in order to obtain each value from each key as a list `[[1,2],[3,4]]`.

```
 final_matrix = []
 for sequence in data:
                temporal_list = []            
                for key, value in sequence.items():    
                     parsed_value = json.loads(value)
                     temporal_list.append(parsed_value)
                     
                final_matrix.append(temporal_list)
 np.save(file_path, np.array(final_matrix, dtype=object), allow_pickle=True)
```

Saving this gives me `Memory Error` from numpy, but if the value is not parsed with `json.loads`, and just sequence is appended to `temporal_list`, then it can be saved properly. I can just save this and whenever I need to use the values, use the parsing and no further problems but I am now questioning... Why is this? Is it because it's different to save actual lists rather than strings?

Error code:

```
    np.save(file_path, np.array(final_matrix, dtype=object), allow_pickle=True)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in save
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 530, in save
    pickle_kwargs=dict(fix_imports=fix_imports))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 680, in write_array
    pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=3, **pickle_kwargs)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: My bad, Done! @MichaelButscher